# Bulk add indexing to tables via migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I am aware of the ability to do a 'Rails Bulk Migration' but only in the instance of adding multiple new columns to the same table.

Is there a way to use the same bulk method but use it to add multiple indexes to e.g. 3 columns in the same table.

An example could be a Car table that contains multiple columns including colour, power and manufacturer. Say I want to add indexing to those specific 3 columns. How would this be done?

It would save me having to do

```
add_index :car, :power, unique: true
```

etc another two times.

Comment: bulk migration doesn't save you from having to define the indexes, it's a tool to package up the changes into a single alter statement. And yes you can set up indexes within a bulk change. change_table :table_name, bulk: true do |t| t.index :power, unique: true end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_index` is part of [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html) which is the clunky low level API and like almost all its methods you can call them via [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html) which provides a table based abstraction:

```
change_table :cars, bulk: true do |t|
  t.index :power
  t.index :foo
  t.index :bar
end
```

Comment: Ah ok, I was over-complicating it. Thanks so much!